# Flutter MQTT Client Detached socket cant implement both 'Stream<List<int>>' and 'Stream<Uint8List>'

Tags: flutter, dart, mqtt

I have a running mosquitto broker runnng in a public ip lets say  234.56.xx.345 at port 1883.
I am making an android app based on flutter to share some information after sometime. I included the mqtt flutter package but on compiling I get an error. Below find my code.

The error i get is 
Compiler message:

```
file:///home/cccc/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/mqtt_client-5.5.3/lib/src/connectionhandling/mqtt_client_mqtt_ws2_connection.dart:11:7: Error: '_DetachedSocket' can't implement both 'Stream<List<int>>' and 'Stream<Uint8List>'
 - 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Uint8List' is from 'dart:typed_data'.
class _DetachedSocket extends Stream<List<int>> implements Socket {
      ^
Compiler failed on /media/ccc/PRO/yebdriver/lib/main.dart
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Below is my mqtt client initialization code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:mqtt_client/mqtt_client.dart';


final MqttClient client = MqttClient('test.mosquitto.org', '');

Future<int> mqqtClient() async {

  client.logging(on: false);
```

message that is not the default(60s)
      /// you must set it here
      client.keepAlivePeriod = 20;

```
  /// Add the unsolicited disconnection callback
  client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;

  /// Add the successful connection callback
  client.onConnected = onConnected;

  client.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;


  client.pongCallback = pong;

  /// Create a connection message to use or use the default one. The default one sets the
  /// client identifier, any supplied username/password, the default keepalive interval(60s)
  /// and clean session, an example of a specific one below.
  final MqttConnectMessage connMess = MqttConnectMessage()
      .withClientIdentifier('Mqtt_MyClientUniqueId')
      .keepAliveFor(20) // Must agree with the keep alive set above or not set
      .withWillTopic('willtopic') // If you set this you must set a will message
      .withWillMessage('My Will message')
      .startClean() // Non persistent session for testing
      .withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
  print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connecting....');
  client.connectionMessage = connMess;


  try {
    await client.connect();
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    print('EXAMPLE::client exception - $e');
    client.disconnect();
  }

  /// Check we are connected
  if (client.connectionStatus.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
    print('EXAMPLE::Mosquitto client connected');
  } else {
    /// Use status here rather than state if you also want the broker return code.
    print(
        'EXAMPLE::ERROR Mosquitto client connection failed - disconnecting, status is ${client.connectionStatus}');
    client.disconnect();
    exit(-1);
  }

  /// Ok, lets try a subscription
  print('EXAMPLE::Subscribing to the test/lol topic');
  const String topic = 'test/lol'; // Not a wildcard topic
  client.subscribe(topic, MqttQos.atMostOnce);

  /// The client has a change notifier object(see the Observable class) which we then listen to to get
  /// notifications of published updates to each subscribed topic.
  client.updates.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
    final MqttPublishMessage recMess = c[0].payload;
    final String pt =
    MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(recMess.payload.message);


    print(
        'EXAMPLE::Change notification:: topic is <${c[0].topic}>, payload is <-- $pt -->');
    print('');
  });

  /// If needed you can listen for published messages that have completed the publishing
  /// handshake which is Qos dependant. Any message received on this stream has completed its
  /// publishing handshake with the broker.
  client.published.listen((MqttPublishMessage message) {
    print(
        'EXAMPLE::Published notification:: topic is ${message.variableHeader.topicName}, with Qos ${message.header.qos}');
  });

  /// Lets publish to our topic
  /// Use the payload builder rather than a raw buffer
  /// Our known topic to publish to
  const String pubTopic = 'Dart/Mqtt_client/testtopic';
  final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
  builder.addString('Hello from mqtt_client');

  /// Subscribe to it
  print('EXAMPLE::Subscribing to the Dart/Mqtt_client/testtopic topic');
  client.subscribe(pubTopic, MqttQos.exactlyOnce);

  /// Publish it
  print('EXAMPLE::Publishing our topic');
  client.publishMessage(pubTopic, MqttQos.exactlyOnce, builder.payload);

  /// Ok, we will now sleep a while, in this gap you will see ping request/response
  /// messages being exchanged by the keep alive mechanism.
  print('EXAMPLE::Sleeping....');
  await MqttUtilities.asyncSleep(120);

  /// Finally, unsubscribe and exit gracefully
  print('EXAMPLE::Unsubscribing');
  client.unsubscribe(topic);

  /// Wait for the unsubscribe message from the broker if you wish.
  await MqttUtilities.asyncSleep(2);
  print('EXAMPLE::Disconnecting');
  client.disconnect();
  return 0;
}

/// The subscribed callback
void onSubscribed(String topic) {
  print('EXAMPLE::Subscription confirmed for topic $topic');
}

/// The unsolicited disconnect callback
void onDisconnected() {
  print('EXAMPLE::OnDisconnected client callback - Client disconnection');
  if (client.connectionStatus.returnCode == MqttConnectReturnCode.solicited) {
    print('EXAMPLE::OnDisconnected callback is solicited, this is correct');
  }
  exit(-1);
}

/// The successful connect callback
void onConnected() {
  print(
      'EXAMPLE::OnConnected client callback - Client connection was sucessful');
}

/// Pong callback
void pong() {
  print('EXAMPLE::Ping response client callback invoked');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flutter version is using Dart 2.5, the MQTT client is still on Dart 2.4.x as this is the current stable release, you can use the development branch of the mqqt_client repo, see this [issue](https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/issues/103)

Comment: I suspected this to have been the issue but u was not sure.

Comment: I have dart 2.4.x installed but how do I set flutter to use the dart rather than use the 2.5 in the cache

Answer (score 0):

Your better of asking the flutter devs but I'm sure you cant mix latest flutter and dart 2.4.x